# Update all record matching some conditions but keeping "position-indexed" values in a database table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I have a `position` database table column in order to handle a sortable list of records. I would like to update that column for all records matching some conditions on destroying a record which `position` value is "in the middle of all position values", but keeping the order (numerically) in the `position` column.

That is, for example, if in the following list of class objects I destroy the record with `position` *3* and `user_id` *1*

```
#<Article id: 1, position: 1, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 2, position: 1, user_id: 2>,
#<Article id: 3, position: 2, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 4, position: 3, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 5, position: 1, user_id: 3>,
#<Article id: 6, position: 4, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 7, position: 5, user_id: 1>,
#<...> # A lot of others records having 'user_id' = 1
```

I would like to update all other records related to `user_id` *1* so to have

```
#<Article id: 1, position: 1, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 2, position: 1, user_id: 2>,
#<Article id: 3, position: 2, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 5, position: 1, user_id: 3>,
#<Article id: 6, position: 3, user_id: 1>,
#<Article id: 7, position: 4, user_id: 1>,
#<...> # A lot of others records having 'user_id' = 1
```

Of course, all that being careful to performance.

**How can I do that** (maybe in a single clause\statement)**?**

---

I know that the `update_all` method can help someway, but I don't know how to auto-increment `position` values using that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for in SQL is this?

```
update articles set position = position - 1 
       where position > pos_of_deleted and user_id = uid_of_deleted
```

With `update_all` it should convert to something like this:

```
Article.update_all("position = position - 1", 
                   ["position > ? and user_id = ?", 
                    pos_of_deleted, uid_of_deleted])
```

That will pull all positions above the deleted position down one notch..

Comment: That is just pure SQL as an example for you. You can ignore it if you're not familiar with SQL directly. Just look at the update_all code instead :)